# Typings/autocomplete suggestions for custom library not coming in Expo projects

Tags: expo, react-native, react-native-ios, typescript-typings, callstack

I made a library with Typescript and React Native and published it on npm, but when I'm using it in any expo project I'm not getting any typings or autocomplete suggestions. Can anyone tell me the steps to solve this issue? Also, I've used Callstack react-native-builder-bob for the setup of this library.

My tsconfig right now is :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "paths": {
      "my-library": ["./src/index"]
    },
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  }
}
```